# I want to delete the Firebase database child, but I can't

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete the Firebase database child with this follow code when I click the first item in a list in an app, but I can't. What's wrong?

```
Query removeCalendar = mCalendarDatabaseReference.limitToFirst(1);
removeCalendar.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       String remCal = dataSnapshot.toString();
       mCalendarioDatabaseReference.child(remCal).removeValue();
       }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
       }
   });
```

Comment: can you post your database structure?

Comment: I solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Queries return a list of possible locations where the query might be satisfied, you'd need to iterate through your dataSnapshot to access those locations. Moreover, this :

```
String remCal = dataSnapshot.toString();
```

is not going to print the String value of this snapshot. If you want to get the string value of a dataSnapshot it should be:

```
String remCal = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

If you want to get the reference of a datasnapshot just use getRef(), you don't have to access the original reference.

```
Query removeCalendar = mCalendarDatabaseReference.limitToFirst(1);
removeCalendar.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            child.getRef().setValue(null); //deleting the value at this location. You can also use removeValue()
        }
       }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with this code:

```
Query removerCalendario = mCalendarioDatabaseReference.limitToFirst(1);
removerCalendario.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        ds.getRef().removeValue();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `mCalendarioDatabaseReference.child(remCal).setValue(null);`